# Upload folder in Blob Storage with SAS URI

Tags: python, upload, azure-blob-storage

I have to upload a set of folders into a dedicated container in Azure Blob Storage.
I found this:
https://github.com/rahulbagal/upload-file-azure-sas-url
but it is just for uploading a file using a dedicated Blob SAS URI, and it works perfectly.

Is there any similar solution able to manage folder upload instead of a file upload?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Please try to use this code:

```
    import os
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

    account_url = "https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/"
    sas_token = "<your-sas-token>"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url, sas_token)
    container_name = "<your-container-name>"
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    local_path = "<your-folder-path>"
    folder_name = "<your-folder-name>"
    for files in os.listdir(local_path):
        with open(os.path.join(local_path,files), "rb") as data:
            blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob= folder_name + "/" + files)
            blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

**2.** Or you can use azcopy to upload your folder:

For example:

```
azcopy copy '<folder-path>' 'https://<account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>?<sas-token>' --recursive
```

For more details, you can refer to this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-upload?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#upload-a-directory).

Comment: thank you. it works. Now I would like to see the file I have uploaded inside the container via python script. Is there any script for doing that?